# Is there a CSS/JS minification and bundling tool for ASP.NET that supports explicit CDN uploads?

Tags: cdn, minify

There is a lot of action in the CSS/JS bundling+minification space with MVC4 and things like Cassette, but I can't seem to find one that supports uploading to a CDN natively.

We use Rackspace Cloud Files and it requires that we upload (via their API no less) our assets directly - it doesn't do an origin-pull.

Right now, we have MSBuild script that does this for us, but it is very difficult to maintain and work with.

Comment: Does their API allow you to map a drive and copy files that way or is it purely HTTP?

Comment: There are a few tools out there that can do use some tricks to fake a mapped drive, but they aren't quite as stable/reliable as I'd like. What did you have in mind?

Comment: For the record, we abandoned Cloud Files and switched to Cloudfront so we could just use Cassette. Some more details here: http://blog.coreyh.com/?p=1507

Answer (score 0):

If you could map a drive, I think [RequestReduce](http://www.requestreduce.com) MIGHT get you what you want out of the box. It performs bundling and minification at runtime and provides some configuration options that allow you to specify the drop location of generated assets to any UNC path. The intent of this config is for web farm scenarios that have a dedicated share for static assets. I'm wondering if this might work for you. It also exposes an interface that allows you to essentially take over the process of saving and retrieving assets from any durable store. It comes with a local disk store and there is a SqlServer store provided as a separate Nuget package. I've had others propose writing ones for Azure blob or amazon ec3. Its a bit involved but not too horrible. At any rate its free, it provides background image spriting and optimization which few others provide and there is another Nuget package that adds Less/Sass/Coffee compiling. Its used by Microsoft on alot of the MSDN/Technet properties.

I run the project and would be happy to answer any questions via the [Github Issues page](https://github.com/mwrock/RequestReduce/issues).